# Android Gallery: how to detect that an item has shifted in Gallery (and shift direction)

Tags: android, gallery, coverflow

I am using a `Gallery` based Cover-flow, as suggested [here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html).
Is there an event that can be caught, which indicates that a single shift (either left or right) has been made in my gallery/cover-flow?
To be clear, if I gave the gallery a decent swipe and my center (selected) image has changed 8 times, I would like to catch this event 8 times.

`OnFling()` just indicates a single swipe - regardless how many items have shifted.
Getting `getSelectedItemPosition()` before and after the swipe doesn't help since I need to do some work on every shift.
It will also be nice while I am at it, to get the direction of the shift - either right or left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should implement [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) interface and set it to you Gallery with `setOnItemSelectedListener` method, also `setCallbackDuringFling`might be usefull.
To get fling direction you can save last selected position and compare it with new one.

Comment: Nikolay, thank you for your reply. I have already tried both your suggestions, but they do not accomplish what I need. They are not called on every shift of an item and I need to do some work on every item shift, meaning - every time the image in the center changes.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, although this solution does not raise an event on every shift, it does do so on every 2 or 3 shifts. If my gallery has 20 elements, I can catch events for elements 0,2,5,7,9,11,14,16,19 - for example, which is good enough. Therefore, I embrace your solution and thank you very much.